# creating list of strings that matches regex pattern while iterating through multiple files

Tags: python, regex, list

I'm iterating through files in one direcotry. All of them have the same structure:

```
3.1  Receiver Type            : ASHTECH UZ-12
     Satellite System         : GPS
     Serial Number            : UC2200303016
     Firmware Version         : CN00
     Elevation Cutoff Setting : 3 deg
     Date Installed           : 2008-07-15T00:00Z
     Date Removed             : 2008-12-29T00:00Z
     Temperature Stabiliz.    : NONE
     Additional Information   : 


3.3  Receiver Type            : TRIMBLE NETR5
     Satellite System         : GPS+GLO
     Serial Number            : 4917K61764
     Firmware Version         : 4.03
     Elevation Cutoff Setting : 3 deg
     Date Installed           : 2009-10-15T20:00Z
     Date Removed             : 2010-08-27T12:00Z
     Temperature Stabiliz.    : 
     Additional Information   :
```

And I want to create list of receiver types (`['ASHTECH UZ-12', 'TRIMBLE NETR', ...]`) but function created by me returns empty list of lists, probably by using regex wrong but I don't know how to fix it. Could someone help? Here is the function:

```
def logs_reader():
    path = Path("C:\\Users\\" + getpass.getuser() + "\\DCBviz\\logs\\")

    file_list = [f for f in path.glob('**/*.log') if f.is_file()]
    
    receiver_list = []
    for file in file_list:
        with open(file, encoding='utf8') as f:
            receiver_models = re.findall('.^Receiver type.:*(\S+\n)', f.read())
            receiver_list.append(receiver_models)
            print(receiver_list)
logs_reader()
```

Comment: You have a beginning of line anchor (`^`) after the `.` that requires a character to match it - not surprised the regex as a whole isn't matching anything.

Comment: You could use `re.findall("Receiver Type\s*:\s*(.*?)\s*$", f.read(), re.MULTILINE)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's try,

```
print(
    [x.split(":")[-1].strip() for x in text.splitlines() if "Receiver Type" in x]
)
```

---

```
import re

print(
    [x.strip() for x in re.findall("Receiver Type\s+:(.+)", text)]
)
```

---

```
['ASHTECH UZ-12', 'TRIMBLE NETR5']
```